# Android studio window size too big

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed android studio on my windows 7 machine. The window size (run configurations, add activity...) is bigger than my screen and I am unable to click on the finish button after doing my selections. If I drag the window up it would jump back down when it reaches the top part of my screen. There is [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180749#makechanges) filed. Does anyone know some kind of work around? It is becoming a real pain to me in my development works.[image]
Update:I am able to resize the window horizontally but not vertically.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the windows snap shortcut to change it's alignment and size. Try Windows key + Left/Right arrow key.

Comment: You can also do WinKey + UpArrow to maximize the window, which should make it resize to fit the screen.

Comment: The right/left arrow keys are working but not the up/down. I will edit my question to make it clear that I am able to resize the window horizontally not vertically.

Answer (score 4):

I went to file - settings. Then under appearances and behavior, I selected the theme drop down menu and selected windows. Under windows options I ticked 'Widescreen Tool Window layout' and last but not least, under presentation mode I selected the lowest possible font size available. Let me know how you go, it has worked for me so far.

Comment: Please don't sign the posts you make. They are already signed by the system with your username.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer we can take it as a shortcut.

Follow the steps:

1. Click on "Start a new Android Studio Project"
   It will open window, Fill up details by pressing TAB to go NEXT, NEXT.
2. After filling up details, Your cursor is in "Project Location" Area (If not then click on that) and Press TAB.
   It will focus on "Next" Button, You can Press "Enter" now.
3. Now you are in next screen "Target Android Devices".

I got the solution for this screen by Maximizing the window (see the attachment). (If you cant get even then you should choose way of TABs again.)

Its work for me for all the screen except first screen (Maximizing the Window).

Answer (score -1):

You can use ALT+SPACE to get the window menu, click "move" and use your cursor keys to move the window around to work with it.  You can also see if "restore" or "minimize" works.  If you have a menu control for your monitor make sure it is set to run the same resolution set in windows (right click desktop, screen resolution).  AS is taking it's window size cue from windows settings, so it might be the monitor or cabling.  I have win7 and AS 1.3.2 and it works normally without the problems you describe.

Comment: your solution moves the window until I move cursor to click on the finish button, it drags the whole window with it and finally releases the window to it's original position. So that is not a solution. Someone downvoted you, it is not me. Thanks for your solution.